# PyCharm and filters for external tools

Tags: python, regex, pycharm, pep8

I'm trying out PyCharm for Django development and so far am extremely happy. My team strictly follows PEP8 formatting and we use the pep8 command line program to check to make sure our code conforms.

I've configured an external tool command to run pep8 and it works good. I see the capability to create filters that will cause the output to be parsed into something PyCharm can use. I've read the docs and searched Google but can't find an example to make this work. Docs are http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/add-filter-dialog.html

I'm using PyCharm 1.2 and the output filter I'm using looks like this:

```
$FILE_PATH$:$LINE$:$COLUMN:.*
```

Example output looks like this:

```
/home/matt/.../settings.py:13:30: E261 at least two spaces before inline comment
/home/matt/.../settings.py:20:80: E501 line too long (126 characters)
```

What would be even more awesome is if this could be run each time the file is saved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've missed a `$` off the end of COLUMN. I followed your steps and I have it working perfectly. Your filter should be:

```
$FILE_PATH$:$LINE$:$COLUMN$:.*
```

Update: To have it work for PyCharm 1.5 use:

```
$FILE_PATH$\:$LINE$\:$COLUMN$\:.*
```

Comment: For parsing doxygen output you have to write `$FILE_PATH$:$LINE$:.*`

Comment: @Sorin Sbarnea, - same for PyFlakes as well.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the the path contains a `!` symbol, and it stops recognizing the `$FILE_PATH$` once it finds the first `!` :(

Answer (score 5):

PyCharm expects full file path for the links to work, not just the name.

Comment: In this case, that path is relative to the project root. Does that make a difference? I changed my config for the external command to use the full path and no change happened. I've updated my example above.

Comment: There's a feature request for relative path support here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-48163 Vote if you'd like it!