# Complete code example that demonstrates all PEP-8 rules

Tags: python, pep8

I want my code to be [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant.
However, reading the PEP8-page everytime I forgot any of the rules is time-consuming. Much faster would be if I had a code example, which demonstrates *all* PEP-8 rules.

Is there any code example out there which does exactly that?

Comment: Sorry, I should Google more next time I want to ask a question on SO.
Here is an example which does exactly what I want: http://wwd.ca/blog/2009/07/09/pep-8-cheatsheet/ However, I would appreciate a more detailed example, since this one is pretty short.

Comment: Your link is now broken; I've added an example answer.

Comment: Wayback Machine to the rescue! https://web.archive.org/web/20120709112020/http://wwd.ca/blog/2009/07/09/pep-8-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org), the last versions (>2.3.0) of [Pydev](http://pydev.org/) can include the pep8 checker, so the check will be done in real-time. As soon you wrote the code, the checker will verify it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to use the IDE for that. Didn't know that this is possible. Since I'm using Pycharm, I followed the advices of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436540/pycharm-and-filters-for-external-tools which gives me nearly (but not) the same comfort.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a gist which claims to be a cheatsheet:

https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/454964087739a449da04

Answer (score 6):

I tend to look at code from established projects with contributor policies including PEP. Here are some examples:

**sklearn:**

- Feature selection [_from_model.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_selection/_from_model.py)
- [logistic.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py)
- Gaussian process [_gpr.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/gaussian_process/_gpr.py)

**Keras:** [training.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py)

**Flask:** [sessions.py](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/sessions.py)

In the examples here, Keras and Flask allow lines longer than 80 characters when necessary which seems common in other projects too. scikit-lean seems to conform exactly in the examples I've seen.

I think this is quite a good example for docstring: [Napoleon](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html). Though it's Google's take on docstring rather than official Python.

Comment: this really is the best answer (although almost all of the links are broken).  Just look at examples from mature projects

Comment: @3z33etm thanks for letting me know. I've updated the links (changed where refactored / removed)

Answer (score 1):

Get [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), the new version include support to make sure that your document is PEP8 compliant and will give warnings on each violation.

Answer (score 0):

Use vim/emacs with plugins. I am vim user so only vim link:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2914